# Angular ui-grid Exporting to Excel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a use case of having large response data from a rest service to the angular ui-grid. Instead of rendering all data at once I want the data to be displayed in batches but the export to excel option should export all the data from the service. Is there a way to do this, maybe incrementally?

Comment: Why not export it to a Google Sheet?  Exporting to Excel raises more questions and Google Sheets can optionally be downloaded as excel files.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Flat Entity Access](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/404_large_data_sets_and_performance) feature, or [Pagination](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/214_pagination) feature. I have tried Pagination and I exported all the data as csv.

Comment: When you export data in pagination, don't you just export the data in that page? I want all data to be exported but displayed in pages

Comment: @VivekAgarwal No, there is the option to export all the data, check this [link](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/206_exporting_data).